# I want to delete data from elasticsearch through nifi by providing url of elasticsearch url

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-nifi

Using `putelasticsearchhttp` processor of apache nifi I'm able to put data in my elastic search by providing elasticsearch url. Now I want to delete and update data from my elastic search and for that when I'm writing delete in `index operation` parameter of `putelasticsearchhttp` processor then it is giving me error shown below.

[image: error I'm facing]

Is it possible to delete the elastic search data using `putelasticsearchhttp` processor of apache nifi if yes then how and if no then what processor should I use and how?

Keep in mind that I'm using elasticsearch url to access elastic search and it is not running in my local.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `delete` operations, the processor needs to know the identifier of the document in order to delete it. It uses the `Identifier Attribute` property to determine the identifier of the document to delete. Ensure your FlowFile has an attribute (let's call it `es.doc.id`) and it contains the identifier of the document to delete. Then set the value of the `Identifier Attribute` property in PutElasticsearchHttp to `es.doc.id`.

Please note that in newer versions of NiFi, PutElasticsearchHttp has been deprecated in favor of PutElasticsearchJson, and thus it may be removed in a future (major) release.

Comment: In case of identifier I can provide name and address as unique parameter to find the required document to delete it. I want to know that in PutElasticsearchHttp processor how to initiate delete operation as I cannot see any parameter which can tell PutElasticsearchHttp processor that it has to perform delete operation. Can you add one more answer to show the example flow of deleting data from elasticsearch.

Comment: You may need to fetch the document you want from Elasticsearch (using the URL), extract the document identifier into an attribute (with EvaluateJsonPath), then put that attribute name into PutElasticsearchHttp

Comment: Thank you for your reply @mattyb The mistake I was doing was writing ${es.doc.id} instead of es.doc.id in Identifier Attribute. Now it's working fine.

Comment: That's an unfortunate part of that property, it refers to the name of an attribute and not its value using Expression Language. That's an anti-pattern so we've avoided that wherever possible since.